# Erro ao fazer deploy com Tomcat 7

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, tomcat, jdbc, deploy

Fiz um app com springboot e quando rodo ele dentro do springboot ele funciona normalmente porém quando gero o war e boto pra rodar no tomcat ele dá uns erros. Já tentei algumas coisas que vi na internet mas até agora nada me ajudou. Não tenho ideia do que esses erros significam nem o que fazer pra resolver, a única que eu sei, pelos logs, é que algo é relacionado ao jdbc ou hibernate...

No manager aparece essas mensagens:

> FAIL - Application at context path /noivas-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT could not be
>   started FAIL - Encountered exception
>   org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component
>   [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/noivas-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]]

E nos logs:

> GRAVE: ContainerBase.addChild: start: 
>   org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component
>   [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/noivas-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]]
>   (continua...)
>
> Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:
>   Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class
>   path resource
>   [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]:
>   Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is
>   javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default]
>   Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is
>   org.hibernate.cfg.beanvalidation.IntegrationException: Error
>   activating Bean Validation integration
>
> Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit:
>   default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is
>   org.hibernate.cfg.beanvalidation.IntegrationException: Error
>   activating Bean Validation integration
>
> Caused by: org.hibernate.cfg.beanvalidation.IntegrationException:
>   Error activating Bean Validation integration
>
> Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/el/ELManager
>
> GRAVE: Error deploying web application archive C:\Program Files\Apache
>   Software Foundation\Tomcat 7.0\webapps\noivas-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start:
>   org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component
>   [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/noivas-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]]
>
> GRAVE: The web application [/noivas-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT] registered the
>   JDBC driver [com.mysql.jdbc.Driver] but failed to unregister it when
>   the web application was stopped. To prevent a memory leak, the JDBC
>   Driver has been forcibly unregistered. jul 19, 2018 9:51:43 AM
>   org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase
>   clearReferencesThreads
>
> GRAVE: The web application
>   [/noivas-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT] appears to have started a thread named
>   [Abandoned connection cleanup thread] but has failed to stop it. This
>   is very likely to create a memory leak. jul 19, 2018 9:51:43 AM
>   org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase validateJarFile
>
> INFORMAÇÕES: validateJarFile(C:\Program Files\Apache Software
>   Foundation\Tomcat
>   7.0\webapps\noivas-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT\WEB-INF\lib\tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar)
>   - jar not loaded. See Servlet Spec 3.0, section 10.7.2. Offending class: javax/servlet/Servlet.class jul 19, 2018 9:51:43 AM
>   org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase validateJarFile
>
> INFORMAÇÕES: validateJarFile(C:\Program Files\Apache Software
>   Foundation\Tomcat
>   7.0\webapps\noivas-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT\WEB-INF\lib\tomcat-embed-el-8.5.31.jar)
>   - jar not loaded. See Servlet Spec 3.0, section 10.7.2. Offending class: javax/el/Expression.class jul 19, 2018 9:51:44 AM
>   org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase findResourceInternal
>
> INFORMAÇÕES: Illegal access: this web application instance has been
>   stopped already.  Could not load .  The eventual following stack trace
>   is caused by an error thrown for debugging purposes as well as to
>   attempt to terminate the thread which caused the illegal access, and
>   has no functional impact. jul 19, 2018 9:51:48 AM
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.TldConfig execute
>
> INFORMAÇÕES: At least
>   one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug
>   logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned
>   but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning
>   can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.

Comment: Não se ainda precisa de ajuda, mas como você fez seu build?

Answer (score 0):

Bom, primeiro como você vai fazer o deploy em um container externo, marque a dependência do container como **provided**, por exemplo, no `pom.xml`altere a dependência para ficar como no exemplo abaixo:

```xml
    <!-- marca o container como provided -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Gere o war novamente e tente fazer o deploy. Abraço.